# How to change details of a mesh using the sapling tree gen after it is created

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

How to change details of a mesh after it is created

I am creating a tree using the sapling tree gen addon

now when the tree is created it we get the small panel on left hand bottom corner with details like branch distribution, branch rings, random seed etc. we fill the details and then create another mesh say a cube and move it , now  how can we edit the details of the first tree created  like change the branch distribution , random seed etc . the add panel is gone and we see the move panel, how can we see the add or edit panel again

(I am new to blender and trying to learn it watching video tutorials on youtube but could not find any thing there.)

Comment: Once you've closed that panel for any edit in Blender, you can reopen it with F6. HOWEVER, once you do something else (literally anything else), that menu is gone forever and your tree is set as a non-procedural mesh.

Comment: thanks for the reply , but this should be a basic feature, blender has been around for years they should consider to include it in future releases. editing should not be limited to scaling, moving etc , the basic mesh editing should be allowed.

Comment: To be fair, it has matured a LOT in just a handful of years so I'm optimistic that soon enough, Blender will continue to drastically improve in areas like this. In the case of Sapling, as it's an add-on (and I'm not sure who develops it), it may or may not be privy to the same level of attention and focus. As it stands it just procedurally generates a mesh once and then it's done. The mesh is no longer [Sapling-generated tree] sadly, but just [mesh]. I'm sorry I can't be more helpful!